# Align environment in R Markdown which works for both docx and pdf output?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

**QUESTION:**

In R Markdown, what is the right way to add a LaTeX `align`-like environment (with and without equation numbering) which will compile and display for both docx and pdf output?

**DETAIL:**

Option 1 below is what I'm going with. But I'd still like the option to have equation numbering and not give up that functionality when I move between docx and pdf output.

This compiles and displays in both docx and pdf output. Hooray! But what if I want equation numbering?

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
 AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
 Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{aligned}
\]
```

This will not compile for pdf or docx output.

```
\[
\begin{aligned*}
 AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
 Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{aligned*}
\]
```

These compile for both docx and pdf output. But these only display in pdf output.

```
\begin{align}
 AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
 Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
 AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
 Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{align}
```

These will compile and display for docx output. But these will not even compile for pdf output.

```
\[
\begin{align}
 AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
 Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{align}
\]

\[
\begin{align*}
 AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
 Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{align*}
\]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  bookdown::word_document2: default
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
 AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
 Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
 AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
 Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{align*}
````

I am using the `*`-environments to get unnumbered equations in PDF. To get numbererd equations, you should use the environments without `*` and [add labels.](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations)

Comment: Adding a caveat to the answer. To have a multi-line environment with equation numbers on *some* of the lines, which works for all of pdf/docx/html output, you *must* have either a `\nonumber` or `(#eq:<eqlabel>)` on *each* line. Via the *add labels* link in the answer, the environment which generates equation (2.2) will *not* work for docx output. Must use `\nonumber` in place of `\notag`.