# Consistent math equation numbering in bookdown across pdf, docx, html output

Tags: r, ms-word, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

In bookdown, is there a LaTeX math environment which numbers each equation, regardless of whether the ouptut is .pdf, .docx, .html? Adding this LaTeX:

```
\begin{align}
   X &= Y \\
   Z &= W
\end{align}
```

Into the [bookdown-demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) outputs the following:

**PDF:** works as expected.

[image: pdf]

**DOCX:** missing equation numbers.

[image: docx]

**HTML:** missing equation numbers.

[image: gitbook]

Notes:

- The output was generated using `pdf_book`, `word_document2`, `gitbook`.
- This is related to an unanswered question of mine: [Align environment in R Markdown which works for both docx and pdf output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912278/align-environment-in-r-markdown-which-works-for-both-docx-and-pdf-output)

**UPDATE:** Merging Ralf's answer below along with other learnings of mine, in bookdown, the following all work consistently and as expected across .pdf, .docx, .html output.

```
Add a single un-numbered equation:

\begin{equation*}
  X = Y
\end{equation*}

Add a single numbered equation:

\begin{equation}
  X = Y
  (\#eq:eq02)
\end{equation}

I refer to previous, equation \@ref(eq:eq02).

Add multiple un-numbered equations:

\begin{align*}
  X &= Y \\
  Z &= W   
\end{align*}

Add multiple equations with numbering for each:

\begin{align}
  X &= Y (\#eq:eq05)\\
  Z &= W (\#eq:eq06)  
\end{align}

I refer to previous, equation \@ref(eq:eq05) and equation \@ref(eq:eq06).

Add multiple equations with a single numbering for all:

\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
      X &= Y \\
      Z &= W   
   \end{aligned}
   (\#eq:eq04)
\end{equation}

I refer to previous, equation \@ref(eq:eq04).
```

Comment: [This looks promising](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47985267/903061). It doesn't provide details, but suggests that with `bookdown` HTML equation numbering can work as well.

Comment: That might just have to be the hack if there's nothing else. But I'd prefer to number each equation within an environment like `align`, `split`, etc., rather than set up separate environments for each equation.

Comment: Is there a way of making this work in Rmarkdown documents that are not using bookdown? I tried the code above, and could not get it to knit to docx with numbered equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For equation numbering support in `bookdown` you need to [assign labels](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations). the following works for me:

````
---
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
  bookdown::word_document2: default
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  X &= Y \\
  Z &= W
\end{aligned}
(\#eq:eq1)
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
  X &= Y (\#eq:eq2) \\
  Z &= W (\#eq:eq3)
\end{align}


See Equation \@ref(eq:eq1) or Equations \@ref(eq:eq2) and \@ref(eq:eq3).
````

HTML Output:

[image]

PDF output is similar. Word output as seen in LibreOffice is pretty bad, but the equation numbers including references are there. So I guess this is a local or LibreOffice specific problem.

Comment: That works for me as well! I missed that note in the bookdown book.

Comment: I second the bad LibreOffice display. The equation numbers appear glued together in the body of the equation.