# How to use same R markdown source to go to HTML, Word, github markdown, and PDF

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am trying to render the same R markdown source document to MS word, git-hub markdown, HTML, and PDF. Options for the compilation are in the header of the .Rmd file, and the choice of output is determined at the command line through the `render()` function. I would like this document to include figure- and equation numbering in all versions, and have cross-references.

I have an equation in my .Rmd file:

```
(\#eq:eq)
A=\frac{\pi}{27d^2}
```

(let's ignore the wrapper for now.)

This is crossreferenced from the text as `(e.g. Equation \@ref(eq:eq))`.

My header  in `main.rmd` looks like this:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    keep_tex: true
    citation_package: natbib
  bookdown::html_document2:
    number_sections: true
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
  md_document:
    variant: gfm
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_md: yes
    number_sections: true
  bookdown::word_document2:
    number_sections: true
    reference_docx: defaulto
```

When I render with **word**...

```
rmarkdown::render("main.rmd",
  output_format=c('word_document2'),
  run_pandoc = TRUE,
  clean=TRUE)
```

If I use `$$` as my wrapper I see the equation label rendered in the Word document. The equation number is given but it is not a cross-reference. I have to use `\begin{equation}... \end{equation}` to get that to work as a cross reference.

When I render to **HTML**, either wrapper option gives me reasonable output.

```
rmarkdown::render("main.rmd",
  output_format=c('bookdown::html_document2'),
  run_pandoc = TRUE,
  clean=TRUE)
```

When I render to **markdown**,

```
rmarkdown::render("main.rmd",
    rmarkdown::md_document(variant = "gfm"),
    run_pandoc = TRUE,
    clean=TRUE,
    knit_root_dir= getwd())
```

I don't get any output when I use ´´´\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}. There I have use `$$ .. $$` to get any output, and I see `Equation @ref(eq:eq)` in the text, i.e. the cross reference does not render at all.

The **PDF** is rendered using

```
rmarkdown::render("main.rmd",
  output_format=c('bookdown::pdf_document2'),
  run_pandoc = TRUE,
  knit_root_dir= getwd())
```

... and seems to work fine in both cases.

So... problem: I cannot use the same equation format to go to markdown, HTML, and word from .Rmd. Is there a solution that can be implemented either in the .Rm source, or when calling `render()`?

## MWE

```
title: "MWE"
author: "Me, myself, and I"
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    keep_tex: true
    citation_package: natbib
  bookdown::html_document2:
    number_sections: true
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
  md_document:
    variant: gfm
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_md: yes
    number_sections: true
  bookdown::word_document2:
    number_sections: true
    reference_docx: default
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=1in
graphics: yes
bibliography: main.bib
linkcolor: blue
urlcolor: red
citecolor: cyan
link_citations: true

# Test{sec:test}

This should be a cross-reference to Equation \@ref(eq:eq).

$$
(\#eq:eq)
A=\frac{\pi}{27d^2}
$$
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44496550/6574038) could be helpful.

Comment: I had also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923290/consistent-math-equation-numbering-in-bookdown-across-pdf-docx-html-output?noredirect=1&lq=1. It looks like there is something broken when going to markdown, unfortunately.